# Impersonate delegated windows account

Tags: impersonation, kerberos, ntlm, delegation, n-tier-architecture

I have 3-layers architecture: Client - Middle Tier - SQL.
I need to delegate client rights to access SQL server.
I made delegation between client - middle tier and it works fine (as I understand).
but middle tier - SQL server connection is over NTLM (cant be changed) which does not support delegation. certainly while connecting it throw with 401 - 0x80070005 "0x80070005 Access is denied. You do not have permission to perform the requested operation".

So I need to to impersonate from MT to SQL delegated from client account. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, you need Kerberos and nothing else, forget NTLM.

Comment: and what about to login on middle tier to make possible impersonation from middle tier? i need any solution for this issue (for beginning)

Comment: How do you intend to gather credentials?

Comment: I'm working on it. If i LogonUser() on MT it work fine =) What about LogonUser on client with LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT and pass token over network. and then create WindowsIdentity() with passed token? Is token local or global on AD?

Comment: This makes sense but beware to encrypt all traffic!

Comment: can't find any usage examples. what should i do with token? and how can i retrieve token on client machine without password (from current identity)?

Comment: how can i check is my credentials on middle tier can be delegated? for example when i call DuplicateToken() with Delegation argument it fail with 1346 error

Comment: all machine accounts must be trusted delegation. Ask your admin for first.